# How to call a function onClick which is defined in React Hooks useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
    useEffect(() => {
    //Calling this function
    const handleClick = () => {
      const lazyApp = import("firebase/app")
      const lazyStore = import("firebase/firestore")
//Some code here

    }
  }, [])

//Calling the function here
<MDBBtn
            to=""
            className="btn p-0 btn-white bg-transparent"
            title="Add To Cart"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faShoppingCart}
              style={{ fontSize: "1.3rem" }}
            />
          </MDBBtn>
```

I am trying to call a function after a button click event. But, I want that function to be defined inside useEffect() due to some reasons. I get the error that handleClick is not defined. What is the solution for this?

Comment: `I want that function to be defined inside useEffect() due to some reasons.` What are those reasons?

Comment: Why do you need to define the callback in `useEffect()` as opposed to defining it as a const/function normally?

Comment: @NicholasTower  It's a firebase issue in Gatsby. Firebase doesn't work properly and has to used in a hook method.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Because you can't. That's not how it works. useEffect — without a second param— works like componentDidMount lifecycle.  The function you're calling has already been called when the component is mounted.

I don't know for what reason you're trying to call an onclick function inside of an useEffect, I've never seen anything like that.

Comment: It's a firebase issue in Gatsby. Firebase doesn't work properly and has to used in a hook method when the window is loaded.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I don't know about firebase/gatsby, but why don't you just go with the conventional onclick? I mean, call the function outside the useEffect hook.

Comment: How can we do that?

Comment: Simply declare the handleClick method outside the useEffect. From your code, just cut the handleClick method and paste it below the hook. That will make the function run Everytime  the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](https://kyleshevlin.com/firebase-and-gatsby-together-at-last) describing how to implement in a class component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const lazyApp = import('firebase/app')
  const lazyDatabase = import('firebase/database')

  Promise.all([lazyApp, lazyDatabase]).then(([firebase]) => {
    const database = getFirebase(firebase).database()
    // do something with `database` here,
    // or store it as an instance variable or in state
    // to do stuff with it later
  })
}
```

In your case you will need to mimic that `componentDidMount` via `useEffect` and implement some click handler.

You could try to do the following:

```
let lazyApp, lazyDatabase;
useEffect(() => {
  lazyApp = import("firebase/app");
  lazyDatabase = import("firebase/firestore");
}, []);

const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  Promise.all([lazyApp, lazyDatabase]).then(([firebase]) => {
    const database = getFirebase(firebase).database()
    // do something with `database` here,
    // or store it as an instance variable or in state
    // to do stuff with it later
  })
};
```

This is untested, but maybe that will help.

Comment: Cannot read property 'initializeApp' of undefined. I'm getting this error for this code: const database = getFirebase(firebase).database()

Comment: The values of lazyApp and lazyDatabase is undefined outside the useEffect() method, but it's a promise object inside the useEffect() method. It's a scope issue. Can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this seems weird and like an anti-pattern, this is how you could implement it. Using a `useRef` to keep the reference for your function.

Please check if you really need to do this.

```js
function App() {

  console.log("Rendering App...");
  const click_ref = React.useRef(null);
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    function handleClick() {
      console.log("Running handleClick defined inside useEffect()...");
    }
    console.log("Updating click_ref...");
    click_ref.current = handleClick;
  },[]);

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>App</div>
      <button onClick={()=>click_ref.current()}>Click</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: I'll find a way. Anyways, the solution that you've given does the work, so I can use it, right?

Comment: Is there any other way to do this task provided that you know what I am trying to achieve using React?

Comment: Your code works, but I am getting other warning from React. Please share any other effective method which gets the same result. Thank you.

Comment: Which warning are you getting?